# how to prevent sudo password prompt in bash EXIT trap?

Tags: bash, sudo, trap

Let us assume bash shell script is using trap to perform a cleanup like this

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cleanup() {
  sudo umount /mnt
}
trap cleanup EXIT
sudo mount /mnt
#do long running stuff like sleep 3600
```

Above script would (always depeding on the settings made in `/etc/sudoers`) not only for the user password for `mount` but also again for the cleanup `umount`. Is there any way to setup a trap as such as it is "already loaded with sudo clearance", meaning it is not requiring anothertime the user password.

Ideally it should not be accomplished by running the whole script via sudo. `exec sudo "$0" "$@"` or alike. It should only be -if at all possible- that there is a way to setup the trap to run priveledged

Comment: Why not run the script with `sudo`? It's easy then to use `sudo` inside the script to run commands as an _unprivileged_ user (`sudo -u nobody some-command` or `sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" some-command`) while everything else, including `mount` and `umount` is run by root.

Comment: Or allow passwordless `mount` and `umount` with `sudo`, or use `noauto,user` option to allow mounting as normal user.

Comment: Most of your questions doesn't have an answer selected. None of them solved any of your issues?

Comment: @Kusalananda while the given example only has commands that anyways need `root` priveledges, yet that is only to keep it simple. I mentioned I was alrady thinking that clearly running the whole script as `uid=0` would remove the issue, but also it might be needless  run more code needlessly with elevated right.

Comment: @pLumo the `mount` has only be one example here. I seek if there is amore general solution. One for any comands in `trap` requiring `root`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a `trap`, you could do something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -

sudo mount /mnt || exit
{
  (
    sleep 3600
  ) 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | sudo sh -c 'cat>/dev/null; umount /mnt'
} 4>&1
```

That way `sudo sh...` is started right after `sudo mount`, but `umount` is only started when the pipe is closed, that is when the subshell that here has `sleep` in it terminates.

Also note that you can tell `mount` that ordinary users can mount `/mnt` via `/etc/fstab` and the `user`, `group`, `users` or `owner` options. See the mount(8) and `fstab(4)` man pages for details.

Comment: that is an interesting option. I have to look into how it is different from `trap` EXIt, hence if the "closed pipe" equivalent to catch all exits.
I know about options to setup `mount`/`umount` to work without root, or how to setup `/etc/sudoers`, indeed the core of the question is indeed for a solution that would  not require to have those solutions and `umount` was only an example command requiring root. thanks for your answer / idea

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea how to make the umount command run as root with the same sudo credentials even if the credentials are timed out before the command completes:

Create a temporary file which will be used as signal to keep the mount point mounted and remove that file in the cleanup hook. Setup a watcher script which is run as root with sudo and watches for the removal of that file and does the unmounting when its removed.

```
#!/bin/bash

keepmounted=$(mktemp -t keepmounted.$$.XXXXXX)

cleanup() {
    rm -f "$keepmounted"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

touch "$keepmounted"

sudo mount /mnt
sudo sh -c "while test -e $keepmounted; do sleep 0.5; done; umount /mnt" &

echo "Doing long running task..."
sleep 3
sudo -k  # Reset cached credentials to simulate long enough time
echo "done."
```

Comment: thanks. A solution with a `while` + `sleep` busy loop is really possible and by this a valid answer. Somehow it yet have to admit, that while I can definitively see myself using that approach it feels not really "right" - as in I would feel a bit unseasy commiting code with it. Yet cannot my finger on why it feels uneasy. Thanks yet. very  creative :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOPASSWD` modifier in `sudoers`, e.g.

```
humanityANDpeace ALL = NOPASSWD:/bin/umount /mnt
```

Of course that would allow you unmount `/mnt` *any* time, regardless of what was mounted there. But changing to some other mount point that has no other uses might be a simple workaround for that.

Comment: I am sorry I failed to better expressed, that I was not looking for this "solution" via `sudoers`. I wanted to make it clear in the question , seems I failed ,sorry.
The solution sought was one where one where it was resolved inside of the script, not via requiring modifying `/etc/sudoers`